# Serial number of device that presented upon adb devices

Tags: android

Iam using a command: 
adb devices

and get this:
C:>adb devices
List of devices attached
HT9CTP820385    device

My question is: 
where this serial number comes from?
Does it burned on flash of device one time during a manufectoring 
or adb drivers assignes it dynamically
or it comes with release that is burned on device?

Answer (score 3):

On the samsung g2 this number is written in `/sys/class/android_usb/f_accessory/device/iSerial`.
It can be retrieved by executing `adb get-serialno`.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same number (as the adb gives me) printed under battery inside my device. So, I guess, it's one-time burned on flash of device.

However, I cannot guarantee that it cannot be overwritten by the same process as flashing new firmware/bootloader/radio.

Answer (score 2):

It's the device number deeply embedded in to the device itself. Every single device that connects to a computer (practically) has one of these (In one form or another). It has nothing to do with drivers.

Comment: But what api returns the answer ? 
It is importent to me to get anderstand in details this process 
of serial number retrival

Comment: That depends which operating system you are on. In Linux you can use sudo lsusb -v | grep iSerial. It'll probably be the one that is a combination of letters and numbers. On Windows, you have to open of the device properties for that device from the device manager. In Android and others I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a bit off-topic, but useful to know:

For all of the devices I tested, the value returned by `Build.SERIAL` (in `android.os.Build`) returns the same as that returned by `ADB DEVICES`.

It probably won't be true for all manufacturers, but is worth checking on your test devices.

Answer (score 0):

It an old question but might help someone so sharing my answer.

Go to -> settings-> About -> status

There you will find "Serial Number" which is displayed when you run "adb devices".

Hope it help.